# Clickable url div in ace editor text

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have an ace editor "textarea" and inside it I have a span with the class "ace_underline". This span is basically a url and I want to be able to catch the mouseup event on it.

I know that I can catch stuff like this

```
 editor.on("click", function(evt) { //something; });
```

but I want to be able detect only when I'm clicking on top of the "ace_underline" span.
Could someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it, still needs some fixing up in some cases but it's working:

```
var handler = function(e){
    var editor = e.editor;

    var pos = editor.getCursorPosition();
    var token = editor.session.getTokenAt(pos.row, pos.column);
    if (/\bmarkup.underline\b/.test(token.type)) { 
            window.open(token.value); // opens the link
        }

}
Editor.on("click", handler);
```

It was based on this: [github link](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/646)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string for the second argument of `.on()` that is a selector for elements within the parent:

```
$(editor).on('click', 'span.ace_underline', function(evt) {
    // $(this) is the span element
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Analog, but it's not working. I can't find the documentation for that argument, aren't you talking about jquery on by any chance? Im trying to do this inside an ace editor, I think it's a bit different.

Comment: Yes, this is a JQuery example. I should have mentioned that. I saw the `.on()` method and assumed you were using JQuery. My apologies.